# How to disable form submission when enter is pressed on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

**UPDATE: I am constructing the form via Javascript, so the form is not there on page load.**

I have an input field with `id="input"`, whenever the `enter` key is pressed, the form gets submitted. So I tried handling it like this.

```
$("#input").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert("enter pressed");
        return false;
    }
});
```

However this does not work, there is no alert and the form still gets sent. How do I solve this?

Comment: I think you are referring to the `submit` event

Comment: @funcoding yes exactly

Comment: So change your code to use `submit` instead of `keydown` event

Comment: hitting enter to submit a form, when inside of a text input, is expected behavior for many users.  As standard text inputs don't allow for character returns, I'd ask why someone is hitting enter when in one of these inputs to begin with?

Comment: @scottohara right they shouldn't but I want to write a function to prevent this

Answer (score 2):

Use `preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting.

```
$("#input").keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("enter pressed");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Example with a form:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aya6ockv/

Answer (score 1):

Use onkeypress attribute in your input as follows:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction(event)">
<script>
function myFunction(event) {
    var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if(x == 13) {
        alert("enter pressed");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I get the alert message, however, `return false` is not stopping the form from being submitted

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this and change 'form' to #input. Unless you want to stop this enter submission site wide, then this as is should work well.

```
$("form").bind("keypress", function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
     return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just created a JSFiddle that shows that it works. Check it out

```js
$('#input').keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('alert pressed');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
  <input text="name" id="input">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: does this have to go into the document.ready function or can it be an independent function

Comment: I don't understand why this is not working for me, could it be that my form is constructed via Javascript instead of on page load

Comment: even if the form is constructed via Javascript?

Answer (score -1):

return false is more efficient than e.preventdefault(). Please look at [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

```js
$("#input").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        alert("enter pressed");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: if you are using, you can reliably use "which". i just updated my answer. And I suggest instead of using keydown use "keypress".